# Select que no puedo validar con javascript en semantic ui

Tags: php, javascript, semantic-ui

Tengo en un formulario, tres SELECT dos de ellos son múltiples y uno es un select simple. Estoy usando el sistema de validación de formularios de semantic ui. Logro validar todos los campos, pero hay uno solo que no me valida.

```
<div class="field">
    <label>País:</label>
    <select id="paisnom" class="ui fluid search dropdown" name="paisnom" required>
         <option value="0"></option>
         <?php
         $conexion = new Conexion();
         $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT paiscod, paisnom FROM paises ORDER BY paisnom");
         $stmt->execute();

         while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         if ( $row['paiscod'] == $pais ) { ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $row['paiscod']?>" selected><?php echo ($row['paisnom'])?></option>
         <?php } else { ?>
             <option value = "<?php echo $row['paiscod']?>"><?php echo ($row['paisnom'])?></option>
         <?php }
         }?>
    </select>
    </div>
```

de esa forma cargo el select de país... y a continuación cómo lo valido

```
dropdown3: {
            identifier  : 'paisnom',
            rules: [{
                type   : 'empty',
                prompt : 'Por favor, tiene que elegir un país de residencia'
            }]
        },
```

así valido uno de los otros dos select

```
dropdown2: {
            identifier : 'intereses[]',
            rules: [{
                type   : 'empty',
                prompt : 'Por favor, elija algunos temas de su interés'
            }]
        },
```

tiene los corchetes rectos al final porque es un select multiple

que puede ser que este pasando ?
 alguna sugerencia ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas en el ejemplo de la [documentación](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#/examples), para que la validación de `empty` funcione, el valor del campo debe estar realmente vacío, en este caso, sería `<option value=""></option>`:

```js
$('.form')
  .form({
    on: 'blur',
    fields: {
      dropdown: {
        identifier  : 'dropdown',
        rules: [
          {
            type   : 'empty',
            prompt : 'Please select a dropdown value'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
<form class="ui form">
  <div class="field">
    <label>País</label>
    <select class="ui dropdown" name="dropdown">
      <option value="">Selecciona</option>
      <option value="arg">Argentina</option>
      <option value="col">Colombia</option>
      <option value="mex">Mexico</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="ui submit button">Enviar</div>
  <div class="ui error message"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Qué maestro @Shaz !!!